# What is wrong with my init.d script [Segmentation fault]

Tags: shell-script, init-script, init.d

I currently filter out data from a MQTT live stream. I then dump this datum into a csv file named `mqtt.csv` and the dumping process is done by `executor_start_up_job.txt` which is written in BASH.

I want to make the dumping of the filter daemon, i.e. in the background, and also want to make it in so that every time the system is rebooted it is done automatically. So I've concluded to write an `init.d` script, and contents of my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

requested_command=$1

start() {

        /home/ed/start_up_job/executor_start_up_job.txt &
}
# Restart the Dump
stop() {

        killproc executor_start_up_job.txt
        echo
}
### main logic ###
case $requested_command in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        last_line=`cat mqtt.csv | tail -1`
        echo "last print line: $last_line"
        ;;
  restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Once I have inserted `set -x` I get the following output:

```
+ ./MySQL_table_update_daemon.sh start
+ requested_command=start
+ start
+ exit 0
```

**Q:** It's my first time writing an `init.d` and I have written my code based on this [example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html) it doesn't work, as I get the error "`segmentation fault`"

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: @jasonwryan, yeah I have, but it just says "segmentation fault"

Comment: Are you segfaulting on infinite recursion? It looks like on the second line of the script you are sourcing the script itself! Which will cause it to be sourced recursively again and again. Can you explain that line? (Also, `MySQL_table_update_daemon.txt` is a *very* odd name for something executable that would be found in `/etc/init.d`, as has been pointed out already.)

Comment: @Celada I've got shebang `#!/bin/bash` to make this (`MySQL_table_update_daemon.txt`) an executable. I've commented out the `./etc....daemon.txt` and currently I am trying to make the code run from the terminal but it doesn't work. The output is just nothing, its as if I've just pushed enter from the terminal; my input to the terminal is `./MySQL_table_update_daemon.txt start`

Comment: Run it under `bash -x` to see what it's doing. It might be working find except that `/home/ed/start_up_job/executor_start_up_job.txt` is doing nothing. By the way, that's also a very odd name for an executable. What's with the `.txt` suffix everywhere?

Comment: Better yet (though this won't change the result), change the shebang line to `/bin/sh` and use `sh` instead of `bash` because you don't use any bashisms here so you might as well use the more portable and leaner standard POSIX shell.

Comment: @Celada I've changed my .txt to .sh so the path is `/home/ed/start_up_job/MySQL_table_update_daemon.sh` also I am quite unfamiliar how run a script under `bash -x` ? is this the same as writing in the code `set -xv`?

Comment: Why don't you change it to just `/home/ed/start_up_job/MySQL_table_update_daemon`? That's what makes the most sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21768/discussion-between-3kstc-and-celada).

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work because you have several syntax errors.

You also have some best practices violations.

Use bash -x on your file after correcting the errors to see it run. Read your script carefully and fix the syntax errors.

Some errors:

```
echo "last print line: `cat mqtt.csv | tail -1"
echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|status}"
# missing ;;
```

I stopped looking after 3. Note also it is normal to specify paths to executable files, usually with variables. It is also not normal to execute 'txt' files. You also aren't telling the user that you support 'condrestart' .

Comment: I don't know how to use bash -x ? is this the same thing as `set -x` ?